# java. Необходимо исключить из строки элемент вида 123 123 321,09

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Есть текстовый файл, кторый я хочу распарсить, а именно считать строку с данными но исключив из неё несколько элементов.

Примеры строк:

```
бла-бла-бла 12312312 бла-бла-бла-бла983-бла {1} {12 000 123,09}
бла-бла-бла 123123123123 {3} {020 123,09}
бла-бла-бла 12312312934393123 бла93-бла0-бла {123,09}
```

необходимо при считывании строки избавиться от чисел в фигурных скобках. Если что поставил фигурные скобки для выделения, по факту их нет.
Как их исключить?
Пробовал сплитовать регулярными выражениями что то типа:

```
String b = "строки";
String[] a = b.trim().split("^(?!0.*$)([0-9]{1,3}( [0-9]{3})?( [0-9]{3})?( [0-9]{3})?(,[0-9]{2})?)$")
```

Но подозреваю, что делаю не правильно.
Прошу помочь примером.

Comment: Что находится в `b`? Одна строка типа `бла-бла-бла 123123123123 {3} {020 123,09}`? Всегда ли числа в фигурных скобках в конце строки? Попробуйте `String result = b.replaceAll("(?:\\s*\\{[^{}]*})+\\s*$", "");`.

Comment: Да, числа находяться в конце строки. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, числа так и висят.

Comment: В b находиться одна из строк, я не стал расписывать весь код, там через for разбираю на части строки.

Comment: Странно, [тут работает](http://ideone.com/bqEGuX).

Comment: Виктор, я так же добавил, что фигурных скобок нет, это я для выделения написал. Так выглядит все в таком виде: бла-бла-бла 12312312 бла-бла-бла-бла983-бла 1 12 000 123,09.

Comment: Это уже сложнее. Может, [`b.replaceAll("\\s[\\s\\d,.]+$", "")`](http://ideone.com/2PqrqN)? Или [`b.replaceAll("(?:\\s*\\d+(?:,\\d+)?)+\\s*$", "")`](http://ideone.com/fQL2Ip)?

Comment: Почему во второй строке остаётся число? Потому что группа больше трёх?

Comment: `(?:[\s,]\d{1,3})+$` [fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/ARRExk/1)

Comment: @vp_arth не очень понятна строка, она так же для метода replaceAll? Если можно полную строку напишите.

Comment: Это регулярное выражение в чистом виде.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо, помогло .replaceAll("(?:\\s*\\d+(?:,\\d+)?)+\\s*$", "")

Comment: @vp_arth понял, спасибо.

Comment: Регулярка, которая вам "помогла" - слишком тяжелая...

Comment: @vp_arth: Это что вы имеете в виду? Она более точная, чем ваша.

Comment: Да ладно, она вырезает число во второй строке. И действительно очень тяжёлая

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте регулярное выражение `(?:[\s,]\d{1,3})+$`:

```
b.replace("(?:[\\s,]\\d{1,3})+$", "");
```

Давайте разберёмся, что происходит:

```
(?:           // Выделяем группу для повтора, но без захвата
   [\s,]      // Пробельный символ или запятая
   \d{1,3}    // От одной до трёх цифр
)+            // Эта комбинация может повторяться
$             // Всё это только в конце строки
```

[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ARRExk/1)

Comment: Отлично, спасибо за пояснения. Работат так же отлично!

Comment: А есть ли литература или полезная ссылка для регулярных выражений, что бы подтянуть знания?! Спасибо.

Comment: Насчёт ссылок не знаю, больше пользуетесь - больше понимаете